# Caml Query between data-times?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, development, caml-query

I want to query all items within 7 days and I have the following code which is working perfectly:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day);

DateTime enddate = startDate.AddDays(7);

query.Query = "<Where>" +
                 "<And>" +
                  "<Geq>" +
                      "<FieldRef Name='Data_x0020_e_x0020_skadimit_x002' />" +
                      "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>" + startDateFx + "</Value>" +
                  "</Geq>" +
                  "<Leq>" +
                      "<FieldRef Name='Data_x0020_e_x0020_skadimit_x002' />" +
                      "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>" + endDatFx + "</Value>" +
                 "</Leq> " +
               "</And>" +                
            "</Where>";
```

This query shows me all items within 7 days but I want to query all items from `Past 7 days` i want to query in the past how can I make that?

Comment: greater than or equal to today -7 and less than or equal to today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
DateTime enddate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day);
DateTime startDate = enddate.AddDays(-7);

                   query.Query = "<Where>" +
                           "<And>" +
                                   "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Kompania' /><Value Type='Text'>" + selectedKompania + "</Value></Eq>" +

                           "<And>" +
                     "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Statusi' /><Value Type='Text'>" + selectedStatusi + "</Value></Eq>" +
                      "<And>" +
                                 "<Leq>" +
                                  "<FieldRef Name='Data_x0020_e_x0020_skadimit_x002' />" +
                                     "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>" + startDateFx + "</Value>" +
                                 "</Leq>" +
                                 "<Geq>" +
                                     "<FieldRef Name='Data_x0020_e_x0020_skadimit_x002' />" +
                                     "<Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>" + endDatFx + "</Value>" +
                                 "</Geq> " +
                               "</And>" +
                               "</And>" +
                               "</And>" +
                           "</Where>";
```

Comment: Do I need to change query now?

Comment: no i dont think so

Comment: unfortunately it is not showing anything anymore the content is blank

Comment: put a break point and check the date values are correct.. Also in the CAML query in your question I can see you are using different date variable.. make sure you are using enddate and startdate